# How to get rid of extra list levels in scheme?

Tags: recursion, scheme

My function below must accept an input that looks like this:

```
(getlist '(a b '(a b) 1 2 '() '(1 2)) )
```

The function must then output a list of all of the lists within the original list. So the output should be like

```
"((a b)()(1 2))"
```

but I am getting this:

```
"((quote (a b)) (quote ()) (quote (1 2)))"
```

I am getting the right values but they are all wrapped inside an extra list with the quotes attached. How do I fix this?

Thank You

```
;function to return all lists in a list
(define (getlist lst)
    ;if list is empty 
    (if (null? lst)
        ;true
        '()
        ;false
        (if (list? (car lst))
            ;true
            (cons (car lst) (getlist (cdr lst)))
            ;false
            (getlist (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: `getlist` implements a `filter`: `(filter list? '(a b (a b) 1 2 () (1 2)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the input list really does contain the lists `(quote (a b))`, `(quote ())`, and `(quote (1 2))`.
The symbol `quote` is never evaluated.

`'` is not a "list-building" operator.
It's shorthand for the `quote` special form, which causes its arguments to not be evaluated.

Since the entire list is quoted, you're not evaluating `'(a b)`– that is, `(quote (a b))`– and the result is the list `(quote (a b))`.

The fix is to remove all the quotes except the outermost one:

```
> (getlist '(a b (a b) 1 2 () (1 2)))
'((a b) () (1 2))
```